# Can I use GraphicsMagick with Craft CMS?

Tags: image-transforms

Short question: Can I use GraphicsMagick with Craft CMS? If yes, how can it be configured? thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, Craft only supports GD and Imagick, not Gmagick (which would be the PHP extension that interfaces with GraphicsMagick). The underlying PHP library, [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine), actually does, so I guess it would be feasible to add support for it, but I suspect that there's not that huge a demand in the community. You could try [submitting a feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) for it.